# D3.js Duplicate values

Tags: duplicates, d3.js

I have a CSV file with music related data (metadata). The data structure looks like this:
Genre, Artist, Track

Genre is first category, Artist is second meaning that a Genre has many artists, and so an Artist may have many songs.

Here is my code:

```
var dataset = d3.csv("musictrackstiny.csv", function(musicdata){    

var genre=d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {return d.genre;})
  .sortKeys(d3.ascending)    
.entries(musicdata);


var g=svg.selectAll("g").data(musicdata).enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",function(d,i) {return "translate("+(120*i)+",0)";});

 g.append("rect")
    .attr("x",cmargin)
    .attr("y",cmargin)
    .attr("width",cwidth-2*cmargin)
    .attr("height",cheight-2*cmargin)
      .append("title")
      .text(function(d) {return d.genre;})

  g.append("text")
    .attr("y",cheight+10)
    .attr("x",cmargin)
    .text(function(d) {return d.genre;})
```

The problem is I see many duplicates `genre` entries in the displays even though I am using the `keys` function.

My end objective is to have a tree/graph with genre as a first node and then `Artists` as its child. The current display using rectangles is to test that concept works. Please note that there will be many genres and artists associated with the songs. I am looking to have a tree structure like this:

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

Comment: just quickly looking at your code - you build a nested data structure and then pass in the original musicdata. Plus for the .data() you should pass the key as the second argument. [link](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data)